# NodeJs - How do I store a users bank account and routing number safely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, bcrypt

I use bCrypt to encrypt the user's password. The `compare()` method bCrypt includes allows a plain text password to be passed and checked against the stored hash in the database.

The issue I am facing is that I need to store a users bank account and routing number, and plain text is outta the question. I figured I could use bCrypt to encrypt the account and routing number, however I would need to compare plain text to the stored hash in order to return the information in it's original state.

This bank account information is viewed by a user with `admin` privileges and not always by the user who owns the bank information. So I would need to fetch the bank account and routing info to display in the admin panel of this application.

How should I approach this? The credit card storage and processing on this application is handled through Stripe, so that portion is taken care of. I was thinking I could use Stripe to store ACH, but I do not need Stripe to process any ACH payments. The bank account and routing numbers are only viewed by the 'admin` for a reference, and are only used in tax preparation.

Comment: This is a bit to broad to be answered. There are so many factors that influence how you would implement it. Ideally the public reachable server would never be able to decode the complete bank information, and even the user would see only a masked version of its data `123 *** *** *** 9` to be able to get a clue if those might be its current bank data. And the decryption can only happen in the internal not public reachable network. And to achieve this you would use asymmetric encryption (public private keys) and the public reachable server would only have the public key pair to encrypt the data.

Comment: "*The issue I am facing is that I need to store a users bank account and routing number [...] I figured I could use bCrypt to encrypt the account and routing number*" which would mean that saving them is somewhat a formality - you would need to ask for these details every time but you'll verify if the ones supplied match the ones from before. However, you'll still presumably use the plain text data you were given, which somewhat defeats the purpose of hashing this, as an attacker has an alternative way to get them now.

Comment: My two cents for this matter is to not forget about PCI and PII compliance. Make sure your server fit those guidelines when you are asking for sensitive information. Keep in mind that storing this kind of sensitive information also opens you up for liability. If you still wish to store this information then I suggest you read the comments above.

Comment: @hafridi I use Stripe for my credit card processing to offload any PCI compliant issues. PCI (Payment Card Industry) typically applies only to card processing, however you can still take note in regards to the PCI standards when storing ACH bank information.